# JSON URL From NBA Website Not Working Anymore

Tags: r, json

I've been working on this project that scrapes data from the nba.com stats website using R. A couple of months ago, I was able to use it easily, but now the url does not seem to work and I can't figure out why. Looking at the website, it doesn't seem like the url changed at all, but I can't access it via my browser.

```
library(rjson)

url <- "https://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?DayOffset=0&LeagueID=00&gameDate=02%2F07%2F2020"

data_json <- fromJSON(file = url)
```

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: If the URL doesn't work any more, that's not really an R problem or generally a programming question. Websites may stop working or decide not to share data at any time. If you want to find out if that data is still available, you would need to contact the website maintainers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a header related issue. The following fixed it:

```
url <- "https://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?DayOffset=0&LeagueID=00&gameDate=02%2F07%2F2020"

  headers = c(
    `Connection` = 'keep-alive',
    `Accept` = 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    `x-nba-stats-token` = 'true',
    `User-Agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
    `x-nba-stats-origin` = 'stats',
    `Sec-Fetch-Site` = 'same-origin',
    `Sec-Fetch-Mode` = 'cors',
    `Referer` = 'http://stats.nba.com/%referer%/',
    `Accept-Encoding` = 'gzip, deflate, br',
    `Accept-Language` = 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
  )

  res <- GET(url, add_headers(.headers = headers))
  data_json <- res$content %>%
    rawToChar() %>%
    fromJSON()
```